# How to extract entity names when it's spread out in several lines of a big text file with python

Tags: python, regex, string, concatenation

I have a large text file in python like below:

```
junk
junk
...
Company          Rent
--------        --------
Andy Candy       2000

Store            0.00

2135  

Moody Group      5000

4512             50%

....
....
junk
junk
....
repeat
```

I want to loop though lines and extract account number and company name. When it loop though first three lines, my idea output should be as below:

```
['2135','Andy Candy Store']
```

then when it loop through the next two lines, the output 
is:

```
['4512','Moody Group']
```

I have attempted with the below code:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    count=0
    for line in f:
        if line.find("----") == -1 and line != '\n' and re.search(
                "Company|Rent", line) == None:
            if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]', line) is not None:
                name = re.findall(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b', line)
                name = ' '.join(name)
                print('name', name)
            elif re.match('^[0-9]', line) is not None:
                number = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
                out = str(number) + ', ' + str(name)
                out = out.split(', ')
                print(out)
```

I got results as below:

```
['2135\n','Store']
```

Any suggestions to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: (1) The indentation of shown code is wrong. (2) The `re` module has no function `research`.

Comment: Sounds like the line-by-line search pattern is: (1) find line beginning with 'Company' followed by line beginning with ('-----'); (2) read first words in next line until two or more spaces are encountered, and continue doing that until (3) a line beginning with a four-digit number is encountered and store the result of (3) followed by (2) and continue looping between (2) and (3) until... what? How do you know when you've hit junk?

Comment: The number is not just limited to four digit... I'm using regex to look for target blocks to process and just ignoring junks.

Comment: @WendyD. We need to know the exact algorithm for parsing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Only slightly adapted your code:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    name = ''
    for line in f:
        if line and line.find("----") == -1 and re.search(
                "Company|Rent", line) is None:
            if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]', line) is not None:
                names = re.findall(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b', line)
                names = ' '.join(names)
                name += names
            elif re.match('^[0-9]', line) is not None:
                number = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
                print([number, name])
                name = ''
```

This assumes that you already correctly separate junk and the logic is correct per se. 
The main fix is the concatenation of name parts in subsequent lines.

If using the file contents above (replacing the junk lines with something not matching the regex), I get:

```
['2135', 'Andy Candy Store']
['4512', 'Moody Group']
```

Comment: I tried that before but got results like ['2135\n','StoreStore']

Comment: I tried it with the few lines you gave and it worked for me. May have forgotten a space and had a typo in the `for` clause - just corrected.

Comment: You are right. I missed a space.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No, it's still not working for me. I think I have may more loops . it's just duplicating instead of combining.

Comment: You did use the code I posted, and get these duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex with flags `/gmi`.

```
^Company\s+Rent\r?\n------*\s+-*\r?\n([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*).*\r?\n(?:([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*).*\r?\n)?(\d+)\s*\r?\n([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*).*\r?\n(?:([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*).*\r?\n)?(\d+)
```

[Python demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZFknV/2/)

This regex has six capture groups:

1. Company name, line 1
2. Company name, line 2 (optional)
3. Numeric identifier following company name
4. Group name, line 1
5. Group name, line 2 (optional)
6. Numeric identifier following group name

If the company (group) name is on one line only, capture group 2 (5) will be `nil`. If the company name is always on two lines and the group name is always on one line, as in the example, the regex can be simplified accordingly. If the company or group name can span more than two lines the regex would have to modified accordingly.

This regex performs the following operations.

```
^
Company\s+Rent\r?\n # match line
------*\s+-*\r?\n   # match line
```

```
(               # begin cap grp 1 (company name 1)
  [a-z]+        # match 1+ ltrs 
  (?: [a-z]+)   # match 1 space, 1+ ltrs in non-cap grp
  *             # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
)               # end cap grp 1 
.*\r?\n         # match remainder of line
```

```
(?:             # begin non-cap grp
  (             # begin cap grp  2  (opt. company name 2)             
    [a-z]+      # match 1+ ltrs
    (?: [a-z]+) # match 1 space, 1+ ltrs in non-cap grp
    *           # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
  )             # end cap grp 2
  .*\r?\n       # match remainder of line
)               # end non-cap group 
?               # optionally match non-cap grp
```

```
(\d+)           # match 1+ digits in cap grp 3 (company id)
\s*\r?\n        # match remainder of line
```

```
(               # begin cap grp 4 (group name 1)
  [a-z]+        # match 1+ ltrs
  (?: [a-z]+)   # match 1 space, 1+ ltrs in non-cap grp
  *             # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
)               # end cap grp 4
.*\r?\n         # match remainder of line
```

```
(?:             # begin non-cap grp
  (             # begin cap grp 5 (opt. group name 2)
    [a-z]+      # match 1+ ltrs
    (?: [a-z]+) # match 1 space, 1+ ltrs in non-cap grp
    *           # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
  )             # end cap grp 5
  .*\r?\n       # match remainder of line
)               # end non-cap grp
?               # optionally match non-cap grp
```

```
(\d+)           # match 1+ digits in cap grp 6 (group id)
```

I understand that Python's regex engine does not support subroutines.  That's unfortunate, as the use of subroutines would have simplified the regex greatly. The PCRE (PHP) engine would allow, for example, each instance after the first of `([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+))` to be replaced with `((?1))`.

Comment: I don't know Python, so cannot post the code to extract the values from the capture groups of each match to construct the desired objects, but I expect it would be straightforward.